# how to draw pie chart in php using chart.js?

Tags: javascript, php, charts

I have php file with some code..In that I have to display single pie chart as well as multiple pie charts for some cases.

How to draw those pie charts using charts.js file.

I dont have any idea about how to use that file for my chart with database data.

Please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume after the php code executes it spits the data using JSON.

Using Chart.js
you can initiate the chart using
`var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx[0]).Pie(data,options);`

and the data is like this

```
var data = [
    {
        value: 300,
        color:"#EEE",
        label: "Cars"
    },
    {
        value: 50,
        color: "#000",
        label: "Buses"
    }
]
```

It will draw the chart for you.

You also need an option object to override the various available options.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply..What if data is from database and how to set legend?